# The meaning of all but sth

Tags: phrase-meaning

While reading some technical book I faced the sentence:

> Experience has shown that disciplined adherence to this approach can
>   ***all but eliminate*** resource management problems

What does the all but expereince mean? Didn't understand that construction. I'd guess that it means the same as

> Experience has shown that disciplined adherence to this approach can
>   ***eliminate*** resource management problems

So, in fact that doesn't affect the meaning at all. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Check the definitions [***all but***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+but).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up the idiom all but in a Dictionary, you will find that it means "almost completely". ".....can almost eliminate resource management problems".

Comment: Uhhhh this is a close reason.